# wp_set_auth_cookie() not working for some users only

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, api

I have a login form and using REST api service for login to the Wordpress. I can login to the wordpress using the form. But for some users wp_set_auth_cookie() function not working and I am getting 502 bad gateway. Can any one help me for sort out this?

This is my login endpoint function

```
function user_authentication() {

    global $wp_rest_auth_cookie;    
    if(strcasecmp($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'], 'POST') != 0){
        throw new Exception('Request method must be POST!');
    } 
    $contentType = isset($_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"]) ? trim($_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"]) : '';
    if(strcasecmp($contentType, 'application/json') != 0){
        throw new Exception('Content type must be: application/json');
    } 
    $content = trim(file_get_contents("php://input"));   
    $decoded = json_decode($content, true);  
    if(!is_array($decoded)){
        throw new Exception('Received content contained invalid JSON!');
    }   
    $user_data['user_login'] = $decoded['username'];
    $user_data['user_password'] = $decoded['password'];
    $user_data['remember'] = false;
    $user = wp_signon( $user_data, false );
    if ( !is_wp_error( $user ) ) {      
        wp_clear_auth_cookie();
        wp_set_current_user ( $user->ID);
        wp_set_auth_cookie  ( $user->ID );
        $wp_rest_auth_cookie =  wp_create_nonce('wp-rest') ;
        $token = encrypt_decrypt('encrypt',$user->ID);  
        $name = get_name($user->ID);

        $response = array(
                    'status'=> 'success',                               
                    'token' => $token,
                    'username' => $name,
                    'uname' => $user->ID                

                    );

        return json_encode( $response);
    }else{
        $response = array(
                    'status' => 'fail',                         
                    'message'=> "The username and password you entered don't match." 
                    );
       return  json_encode($response);
    }


        die();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below code into your code and check wp_set_auth_cookie working or not.

```
$user_data['user_login'] = $decoded['username'];
$user_data['user_password'] = $decoded['password'];
$user_data['remember'] = true;
$user = wp_signon( $user_data, false );
if ( !is_wp_error( $user ) ) { 
   wp_set_auth_cookie( $user->ID, true );       
} else {
   echo $user->get_error_message();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this myself. There was some undefined variable errors along with the api response. Those errors was conflicting with the wp_set_auth_cookie() function. When I fixed those errors from my code, the 502 bad gate way issue get solved.